# How to send SPL tokens from PDA account to user

Tags: pda, anchor-spl

Sending SOL from PDA to user is working as I am using system_instruction::transfer with invoke_signed.

But for transferring SPL tokens from PDA  to user, I can't use the same method as we need to deal with ATAs.

Could you please let me know the process with a working example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example in Anchor. `vault` is a `pda`

my `pda` seeds are `pool.mint`

**Context**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Instruction<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub pool: Account<'info, Pool>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [pool.mint.as_ref()],
        bump = pool.bump
    )]
    pub vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

**Instruction**

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer};

..
pub fn cancel_deposit(ctx: Context<CancelDeposit>) -> ProgramResult {
    let seeds = &[ctx.accounts.pool.mint.as_ref(), &[ctx.accounts.pool.bump]];
    let signer = &[&seeds[..]];
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info().clone(),
        to: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info().clone(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info().clone(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);
    token::transfer(cpi_context, ctx.accounts.user_deposit.amount)?;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share struct definition for Pool Account<'info, Pool>,

Comment: Pool is a simple `account` In this case I'm storing mint, bump and other hings but you can store anything you want.

Comment: `#[account]
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Pool {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub vault: Pubkey,
    pub mint: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}`

Comment: this answer would be way better if it were annotated describing what's going on and why rather than just some copypasta.  no one will learn from it as is

Answer (score 0):

In your Anchor tests:

```
const auth = provider.wallet.publicKey;
```

In your Rust program:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferTokenWithTokenPda<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_pda: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub user_pda: Account<'info, UserPda>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, //associated token account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub auth: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
...
  pub fn transfer_token_from_token_pda(
     ctx: Context<TransferTokenWithTokenPda>, 
     amount:u64, user_pda_bump: u8) -> Result<()>
    {
      let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.user_token_pda.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.ata.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user_pda.to_account_info(),// user_pda!
      };

      let seeds = &[b"userpda".as_ref(), 
          ctx.accounts.auth.key.as_ref(), &[user_pda_bump], ];
//seeds must match how you make your user_pda: 
//const [userTokenPdaPublicKey, userPdaBump] = 
//anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
//[Buffer.from("userpda"), auth.toBuffer()], program.programId);

      let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

      let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();

      let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer_seeds);

      anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount.into())?;
      Ok(())
    }
```