# Can you send Custom tokens and NFTs to a PDA account?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, pda, spl-associated-token-account

I have used PDA account to send and receive sol, now I want to send spl token to PDA Account. What is the implementation for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send SPL tokens from PDA account to user](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/how-to-send-spl-tokens-from-pda-account-to-user)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's already been asked and answered. Here's a link: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/how-to-send-spl-tokens-from-pda-account-to-user?rq=1

Comment: Sending SPL tokens to a PDA token account is no different than sending it a token account which was initialized with a keypair. In fact all associated token accounts are PDAs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I transfer an SPL token using web3.js?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-do-i-transfer-an-spl-token-using-web3-js)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your PDA to be able to receive and send SPL, you can have one instruction in your program for example. This instruction can deposit on the PDA (this is a classic SPL transfer, it can be done without Smart Contract with the lib spl-token (Ex: https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens)).

For your PDA to be able to send SPL, you will need an instruction in your program this time, which will make a Transfer with the `CPIContext::new_with_signer` with the seed of your PDA and its bump, that you can send as an argument or that you can do on your program by rederiving your PDA

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, but your question asking for "the implementation for that" is too broad.